# G++ ubuntu packaging question

Tags: gcc, g++

```
dpkg -s g++
Package: g++
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 16
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: gcc-defaults (1.144ubuntu1)
Version: 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1
Provides: c++-compiler
Depends: cpp (>= 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1), gcc (>= 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1), g++-5 (>= 5.2.1-12~), gcc-5 (>= 5.2.1-12~)
Suggests: g++-multilib
Description: GNU C++ compiler
 This is the GNU C++ compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C++.
 .
 This is a dependency package providing the default GNU C++ compiler.
Original-Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers <debian-gcc@lists.debian.org>
```

If you look at this output, it says Version: 4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1. What does that 4: mean? I mean.. What I believe is true is that the version of g++ is 5.2.1 - correct?

Answer (score 2):

The `4:` prefix to the version number is called the *epoc*.  It is a way for Debian ( and hence Ubuntu, as a derived distribution ) to create a version of a package that is considered higher than previous versions, even if the regular version number is not.  Sometimes various circumstances conspire to cause the need to release a new package that otherwise appears to go backwards in version number, and that is when the *epoc* is incremented.